# operator and operand don't agree error in this simple function

Tags: ml

Consider this definition:

```
fun abs(x:int):int = (x*x)/(~x);
```

which should return the absolute value of the input. But when the function is called, I get this error:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: real * real
  operand:         int * int
  in expression:
    x * x / ~ x
```

What am I doing wrong? Didn't I use `:int`correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SML, `/` is division on reals. For integers, you need to use `div`.

```
> fun abs x = x*x div ~x;
val abs = fn : int -> int
```